# how to store the result in array. and print the data with help of (key,value)pair

Tags: ios, swift

```
let result:AnyObject = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.allZeros, error: nil)!
println(result)
```

data = "{\"0\":{\"pid\":\"100004\",\"encounter_nr\":\"201503024000\",\"consulting_dr\":\"DR.Appaji .\"}\"1\":{\"Systolic_bp\":\"28\",\"Dystolic_bp\":\"29\",\"Weight\":\"22\",\"Height\":\"24\",\"Pulse\":\"26\"}}";
 status = SUCCESS;

Comment: the reult is displayed in console in the above json format  . please tell how to store in array and print

Comment: The above is just rubbish. Would you mind to ask in a meaningful way?

Comment: the result is in json format or not tell me that

Comment: after deserializing iam getting the data in above format. how to store that data in array

Answer (score 2):

You can use below given snippet to store the result in array

```
var err: NSError?
        var jsonResult = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: &err) as NSDictionary
        if(err != nil) {
            // If there is an error parsing JSON, print it to the console
            println("JSON Error \(err!.localizedDescription)")
        }
        let results: NSArray = jsonResult["results"] as NSArray
```

Comment: it is not storing in the array .

Comment: Change the key "results" according to your output key.